# Name output variables using a suffix entered as input

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

How can I name output variables of my function, using a suffix (a string) entered as input of my function, in order to apply the same function more than once, but obtaining each time the results with a different name?

I'd try something like that:

```
import... (what I should import??..)
import numpy as np

def myFun(int, mysuffix)
    a_%s = np.ones(int) %mysuffix
return a_%s
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? Functions can be applied more than once anyway...

Comment: What they said ^.  Why not `myvar1 = myFun(options1);  myvar2 = myFun(options2)` and so on?

Comment: then I suggest a look at the answer of Tino A.

Comment: Because I'd like to have all the outputs (6 vectors and some scalars) with the "right" name, instead of declare all the names each time that I use the function.

Comment: The calling function just doesn't care how called function name its variables, because their names aren't returned like you seems to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to have a list on the receiving end so that you can do e.g.:

```
mylist.append(myFun(int))
```

You can then iterate over the list to get your results.

**EDIT**

You can also use a dictionary instead of a list so that you can still access your results by name+suffix e.g.:

```
 mydict = {}
 for i in range(6): # or whatever your loop looks like
   mydict["a_{0}".format(i)] = myFun(int)
```

Comment: At that time I was a noob in python, but today I know - to use a dictionary - is the right answer! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want dynamic variable names, but this should do what you want:

```
exec("a%s = %s" % (mysuffix, some_other_string));
```

Replace the second argument by the variable type you need.  But most likely you simply want a list of variables.